# Browser connect to raw sockets even possible?

Tags: python, sockets, raw-sockets

We're given this assignment to make a tic-tac-toe game with server-client architecture. My professor wants the server to be built using raw sockets (even lower than TCP/UDP) and client side to be browser. Is that even possible? [Assignment Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fd6Q.png)

I know in the assignment spec it said TCP/IP but I asked my professor later on and she said raw as in lower. This an example of server using TCP she gave (which she doesn't want us to use):

```
# Import the required libraries
from socket import *

# Listening port for the server
serverPort = 12000

# Create the server socket object
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the server socket to the port
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))

# Start listening for new connections
serverSocket.listen(1)


# For python 2.x use the following syntax for displaying strings:
print 'The server is ready to receive messages'

# For python 3.x use the following syntax for displaying strings:
#print('The server is ready to receive messages')


while 1:
        # Accept a connection from a client
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

        ## Retrieve the message sent by the client

        # For python 2.x use the following (no need to convert from byte string to unicode):
        sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)

        # For python 3.x use the following
        # (explicit conversion from byte string to unicode using .encode() method):
    #sentence = connectionSocket.decode().recv(1024)
    
        #Modify the message
    capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()

        ## Send the modified message back to the client
    
        # For python 2.x use the following (no need to convert from unicode to byte string):
        connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence)

        # For python 3.x use the following
        # (explicit conversion from unicode to byte string using .encode() method):
    #connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence.encode())

        # Close the connection
    connectionSocket.close()
```

So she wants us to go even lower than this.

So back to my question, is this possible? I have done some research and seem to find that browsers can't communicate with raw sockets. But she said she has done it, so I don't know at this point.

Comment: You've misunderstood the assignment.  The browser will communicate over HTTP or websockets.  The server needs to implement the server side of the protocol using raw TCP/IP sockets, i.e., no web server framework.

Comment: @MattTimmermans you mean like getting the request and parsing the head and body myself? and then writing a response to send back to the browser? Like this? https://imgur.com/JlrtWqd. I showed her this and she said she wants lower and that's still high level. Is it? if it is guess I'll need to keep on researching

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I wanted to know if the snippet I sent is considered using raw sockets or its still high level?

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's what I did and she said she wanted none of that. Maybe she just can't read Java cause it was recommended to do in python but we could use other languages.  imgur.com/JlrtWqd https://imgur.com/dYhO7JZ These are just snippets from my client thread which runs on the server. You mean like this right? just double checking.

Comment: @Jamescarter you need to get the teacher to clarify the assignment. The Task description you posted suggests a plain ordinary TCP socket (`AF_INET/6`+`SOCK_STREAM`) and a manual HTTP parser, except for the phrase *raw sockets* which is a little ambiguous in this context. If the teacher wants you to go even lower and implement TCP itself using a `SOCK_RAW` socket, than that is much more difficult, if not impossible (ie, because some platforms, like Windows, do not even allow sending TCP data over `SOCK_RAW` sockets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes SOCK_RAW is exactly what she wants us to use. I am trying to tell her that maybe impossible but she is not listening. She said she has done it so idk.

Comment: If you use SOCK_RAW sockets on the server and the client just uses HTTP then you will have to implement the TCP protocol on your own and then the HTTP protocol on top of that, which is not believable for a course assignment.

Comment: @Jamescarter Using `SOCK_RAW` sockets is a very advanced technique, most devs never need to go down to that level as the OS's native TCP/UDP implementation is adequate. You only need to drop to the `SOCK_RAW` level when implementing custom IP protocols (which HTTP is not), or doing packet sniffing, etc. If your teacher is expecting you to use `SOCK_RAW` then they should give you the appropriate knowledge to do it properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with raw sockets, because the built-in TCP module on the server will try to process the incoming TCP packets. Since it won't recognize the port numbers as belonging to sockets it created, it will send RST responses.